# Removing element from wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress

Ive got a link showing up in my wordpress menu that is not present in back end (the costumizer). The link/element only shows up in front end/the live page. I've been in touch with the theme support but they only said it was not from the theme. The code does not either give me an explenation to where it comes from. The code for the element is the following:

Register

LOL I CAN't even write the code without it showing up as only "Register" above.

I want to remove it. I have searched and tried different solutions on this forum but cannot find a way to remove the element.

So far I've tried to add the following code to the "costum css" in the costumizer with no result:

a[href='register']{ display: none }

I am not an expereinced code man. So please excuse my lack of explenation.

See code from inspect in picture below:

[Picture from inspect. The element I want to remove is the >Register just where the pink ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ErD.png)

[This is a picture of the menu. As you can see the "Register" link I want removed does not even get the same styling as the other elements in the menu..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLekq.png)

Any one know how to remove this element? I've been struggeling for so long trying to find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely added to the menu object by one of the plugins you have installed on the site.
Try turning off your plugins one-by-one and checking to see if it goes away.

Comment: Yea, it was a plugin that caused it. However I wanted to keep the plugin and still remove the text. It's been a while now and I've solved it. Do not remember how though. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
.left-menu li:last-child { display: none; }
```

or

```
.left-menu li:not(.menu-item) { display: none; }
```

Comment: The problem is sorted but thanks anyway for the effort!